# Plotting a graph with two separate columns for each axis

Tags: r, plot

I am looking to find a way to use a data frame that has two columns, and I want each column to represent an axis.

| Person | Sex | Lap1 | Lap2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Greg | M | 301 | -12 |
| Harold | M | 33 | -78 |
| Susie | F | 12 | -91 |
| Karol | F | 101 | 201 |

I want to make a scatter graph where column 3 (Lap 1) represents the X-axis coordinate value, and column 4 (Lap 2) is the Y-axis coordinate. So for example, the datapoints would be (301, -12), (33, -78), etc.

I have a lot of rows, so manually doing it would be impossible unfortunately. Is there an efficient way I can do this while also color coding based on sex?

```
Person <- c("Greg", "Harold", "Susie", "Karol")
Sex <- c("M","M","F","F")
Lap1 <- c(301, 33, 12, 101)
Lap2 <- c(-12, -78, -91, 201)
DF <- data.frame(Person, Sex, Lap1, Lap2)
```

Comment: How do you want to colour code? Just the dot colour? Something like `plot(DF$Lap1, DF$Lap2, pch=19, col=c("pink","blue")[factor(DF$Sex)])` maybe?

Comment: Thank you! Would the pink automatically go to F, or how would I usually know which one it color codes for?

Comment: It will depend on the matching order of the `levels` of the `factor` - `levels(factor(DF$Sex))`